# Linux mint:Wireless Device Unclaimed after Upgrade

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, broadcom

After upgrading the mint 18 kernel to `4.4.0-87-generic` I no longer have wireless. My wired device still works, but my wireless nic has disappeared from `ifconfig -a`.

It does show up for lspci:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

iwlist scan; lshw -c net

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71fffff
```

It also shows up in "Driver Manager", so I chose the following:

```
Broadcom Corporation: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless network Adapater:
bcmwl-kernel-source (recommended)
Version 6.30.223.271 +bdcom-Oubuntu1~1.1
Broadcom 201.11 Linux STA wireless driver source
```

I tried rebooting and even booting into an earlier kernel, but still my wireless device is "unclaimed" and does not show up for ipconfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/796) might be useful, basically...

`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

and if something like "An unsupported BCM4312 Low-Power (LP-PHY) device was found." comes out, then:

`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer`

Comment: Awesome, it no longer shows as "unclaimed."  Do I need to restart?  it still does not show up under ifconfig -a.

Comment: yes, please, you need to load your kernel with the new drivers

Comment: Ok, I rebooted, the device is no longer "unclaimed" but still does not show up for ifconfig.  Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: I had some troubles with a broadcom wifi some time ago, check `rfkill list` sometimes the card is hard blocked, if you don't have rfkill, install it with `sudo apt-get install rfkill` try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) link too

Comment: Hmm, yeah I did check rfkill, it was originally soft-killed but I fixed that, I'll take a look at that link.  Anything else you can think of?